# How do I substitute only first occurence with sed?

Tags: sed

Original file

```
claudio
antonio
claudio
michele
```

I  want to change only the first occurrence of "claudio" with "claudia"
so that I would get the following:

```
claudia
antonio
claudio
michele
```

I have tried the following:

```
sed -e '1,/claudio/s/claudio/claudia/' nomi
```

The above command performs global substitution (it replaces all occurrences of 'claudio') . Why?

Comment: Look here http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq4_004.html and also `info sed`: (`0,/REGEXP/`: A line number of 0 can be used in an address specification like `0,/REGEXP/` so that `sed` will try to match REGEXP in the first input line too.  In other words, `0,/REGEXP/` is similar to `1,/REGEXP/`, except that if ADDR2 matches the very first line of input the 0,/REGEXP/ form will consider it to end the range, whereas the 1,/REGEXP/ form will match the beginning of its range and hence make the range span up to the _second_ occurrence of the regular expression)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file

Comment: `awk '/claudio/ && !ok { sub(/claudio/,"claudia"); ok=1 } 1' nomi` should do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you are using GNU `sed`, try:

```
sed -e '0,/claudio/ s/claudio/claudia/' nomi
```

`sed` does not start checking for the regex that ends a range until *after* the line that starts that range.

From [`man sed`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sed.1posix) (POSIX manpage, emphasis mine):

> An editing command with two addresses shall select the inclusive  range
>   from the first pattern space that matches the first address through *the
>   next pattern space* that matches the second.

The `0` address is not standard though, that's a GNU `sed` extension not supported by any other `sed` implementation.

#### Using `awk`

Ranges in `awk` work more as you were expecting:

```
$ awk 'NR==1,/claudio/{sub(/claudio/, "claudia")} 1' nomi
claudia
antonio
claudio
michele
```

Explanation:

- `NR==1,/claudio/`

  This is a range that starts with line 1 and ends with the first occurrence of `claudio`.
- `sub(/claudio/, "claudia")`

  While we are in the range, this substitute command is executed.
- `1`

  This awk's cryptic shorthand for print the line.

Comment: That assumes GNU `sed` though.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  It also works if POSIXLY_CORRECT is set but I guess that doesn't mean as much as I would like. Answer updated (I lack for BSD test machines).

Comment: The awk can, IMO, be simpler with a boolean status variable: `awk '!r && /claudio/ {sub(/claudio/,"claudia"); r=1} 1'`

Comment: @glennjackman or `awk !x{x=sub(/claudio/,"claudia")}1`

Comment: I also could not successfully use a different delimiter in the first part: `0,/claudio/`

Comment: which kind of `sed` wouldn't be able to do this @StéphaneChazelas ?

Comment: @LeviUzodike, all but GNU sed, the 0 address is an extension of GNU sed. AFAIK, no other implementation supports it. In my tests, none of the ones based on the original sed implementation, nor busybox's nor ast-open's nor FreeBSD's nor NetBSD's support it.

Comment: Oh you're talking about the 0 address. I thought you were talking about range addresses that mix line numbers with regex. After reading the answer again, I'm not sure how I thought that lol my bad. Also, cool to know what other `sed`'s there are. I always only see GNU or FreeBSD.Thanks

Answer (score 9):

A new version of GNU `sed` supports the `-z` option.

> Normally, sed reads a line by reading a string of characters up to the end-of-line character (new line or carriage return).
>   The GNU version of sed added a feature in version 4.2.2 to use the "NULL" character instead. This can be useful if you have files that use the NULL as a record separator. Some GNU utilities can generate output that uses a NULL instead a new line, such as "find . -print0" or "grep -lZ".

You can use this option when you want `sed` to work over different lines.

```
echo 'claudio
antonio
claudio
michele' | sed -z 's/claudio/claudia/'
```

returns

```
claudia
antonio
claudio
michele
```

Answer (score 7):

### Sumary

GNU syntax:

```
sed '/claudio/{s//claudia/;:p;n;bp}' file
```

Or even (to use only one time the word to be replaced:

```
sed '/\(claudi\)o/{s//\1a/;:p;n;bp}' file
```

Or, in POSIX syntax:

```
sed -e '/claudio/{s//claudia/;:p' -e 'n;bp' -e '}' file
```

works on any sed, process **only** as many lines as needed to find the first `claudio`, works even if `claudio` is in the first line and is shorter as it use only one regex string.

### Detail

To change only **one line** you need to **select** only one line.

Using a `1,/claudio/` (from your question) selects:

- from the first line (unconditionally)
- to the **next** line that contains the string `claudio`.

```
$ cat file
claudio 1
antonio 2
claudio 3
michele 4

$ sed -n '1,/claudio/{p}' file
claudio 1
antonio 2
claudio 3
```

To select **any** line that contains `claudio`, use:

```
$ sed -n `/claudio/{p}` file
claudio 1
claudio 3
```

And to select only the **first** `claudio` in the file, use:

```
sed -n '/claudio/{p;q}' file
claudio 1
```

Then, you can make a substitution on that line only:

```
sed '/claudio/{s/claudio/claudia/;q}' file
claudia 1
```

Which will change only the **first** occurrence of the regex match on the line, even if there may be more than one, on the **first** line that match the regex.

Of course, the `/claudio/` regex could be simplified to:

```
$ sed '/claudio/{s//claudia/;q}' file
claudia 1
```

And, then, the only thing missing is to print all other lines un-modified:

```
sed '/claudio/{s//claudia/;:p;n;bp}' file
```

Comment: Thank you. Went through quite a few variations, yours finally worked. Could you expand on the "print all other lines" syntax, since you're dropping the "q" there as well?

Answer (score 6):

Here are 2 more programmatic efforts with sed: they both read the whole file into a single string, then the search will only replace the first one.

```
sed -n ':a;N;$bb;ba;:b;s/\(claudi\)o/\1a/;p' file
sed -n '1h;1!H;${g;s/\(claudi\)o/\1a/;p;}' file
```

With commentary:

```
sed -n '                # don't implicitly print input
  :a                    # label "a"
  N                     # append next line to pattern space
  $bb                   # at the last line, goto "b"
  ba                    # goto "a"
  :b                    # label "b"
  s/\(claudi\)o/\1a/    # replace
  p                     # and print
' file
```

```
sed -n '                # don't implicitly print input
  1h                    # put line 1 in the hold space
  1!H                   # for subsequent lines, append to hold space
  ${                    # on the last line
    g                     # put the hold space in pattern space
    s/\(claudi\)o/\1a/    # replace
    p                     # print
  }
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` with a flag to know if the replacement was already done. If not, proceed:

```
$ awk '!f && /claudio/ {$0="claudia"; f=1}1' file
claudia
antonio
claudio
michele
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually really easy if you just setup a little delay - there's no need to go reaching for unreliable extensions:

```
sed '$H;x;1,/claudio/s/claudio/claudia/;1d' <<\IN
claudio
antonio
claudio
michele
IN
```

That just defers the first line to the second and the second to the third and etc.

It prints:

```
claudia
antonio
claudio
michele
```

Answer (score 1):

And one more option

```
sed --in-place=*.bak -e "1 h;1! H;\$! d;$ {g;s/claudio/claudia/;}" -- nomi
```

The advantage is it uses double quotation, so you can use variables inside, ie.

```
export chngFrom=claudio
export chngTo=claudia
sed --in-place=*.bak -e "1 h;1! H;\$! d;$ {g;s/${chngFrom}/${chngTo}/;}" -- nomi
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The general idea is the same. But, please, give a try to substitute single, into double quotes directly, and see if it works. The devil lies in the details. In this example these are spaces and one escape. I believe that this continuation of the earlier answers may save someone's time. And that's the reason why I decided to publish the post.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done without the hold space and without concating all lines into the pattern space:

```
sed -n '/claudio/{s/o/a/;bx};p;b;:x;p;n;bx' nomi
```

Explanation: We try to find "claudio" and if we do it we jump into the small print-load-loop between `:x` and `bx`.  Otherwise we print and restart the script with the next line.

```
sed -n '      # do not print lines by default
  /claudio/ { # on lines that match "claudio" do ...
    s/o/a/    # replace "o" with "a"
    bx        # goto label x
  }           # end of do block
  p           # print the pattern space
  b           # go to the end of the script, continue with next line
  :x          # the label x for goto commands
  p           # print the pattern space
  n           # load the next line in the pattern space (clearing old contents)
  bx          # goto the label x
  ' nomi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/claudia/{p;Q}'

sed -n '           # don't print input
    /claudia/      # regex search
    {              # when match is found do
    p;             # print line
    Q              # quit sed, don't print last buffered line
    {              # end do block
```

Comment: Have you bothered reading the question ?

Answer (score 0):

First pipe some output to awk

#### Then you can use awk variables to substitute

```bsh
cat someFile | awk '!x{x=sub("wordToReplace","wordThatIsReplaced")}1'
```

#### Notice the number near the end.

It is required but can be any number, I chose 1 to signify the first instance.