# sed: print only first occurence of a pattern match

Tags: sed

Several questions are similar to this one, but I have not found a solution that works when I want to search for a pattern over several lines. The following

```
sed -n '/First string/,/Second string/ p' my.file
```

will print *all* occurrences of the matched pattern, but I would like only the first occurrence. I am using GNU sed.

Comment: post your input text and expected output

Comment: First occurrence or first line?

Answer (score 14):

Use `q` to explicitly quit when the end pattern is reached.

In GNU sed:

```
$ cat foo
foo
START
bar
END
blah
START another

$ sed -n '/START/,/END/p; /END/q' foo
START
bar
END
```

`awk` would maybe make it easier to not repeat the end pattern:

```
$ awk '/START/{p=1} p; /END/{exit}' foo
START
bar
END
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's first occurrence you want, perhaps `awk` is better suited for this : `awk 'NR==1,/original/{sub(/original/, "replacement")} 1' file` . Taken from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188264/want-to-substitute-only-first-occurence-with-sed).